# Concatenating two strings in C++ (binary number addition)

Tags: c++, binary, string-concatenation, addition

I have problem with concatenating two strings in C++. What I want to do is to convert a binary number inputted by the user and align its length so that I can further add two numbers inputted. I'm using array of string for input purpose:

```
char* num1, num2;
```

For example user types two numbers:

```
 100010
 1010
```

And I want to process them with the following structure:

```
100010
001010
```

Depending on which string is longer in loop I create another string where I add missing zeros:

```
    char temp2[x];
    for (int i=0; i <(x-y); i++)  //x,y is strlen(num1 or num2)
    temp2[i]=48;
    strcat(temp2, num2);
```

Unfortunately some strange characters appear between two strings and the second string looks like:

```
00d↑ą,@1010 not simply 001010
```

Later on I wanted to convert this string into array of int thus I could use full adder algorithm:

```
for(i = 0; i < lengthofString ; i++){
sum[i] = ((a[i] ^ b[i]) ^ c); // c is carry
c = ((a[i] & b[i]) | (a[i] & c)) | (b[i] & c); 
}
```

Advises on how to solve the problem of adding two different sizes binary numbers are also really welcome.

EDIT: 
OK, so I tried to follow using std::bitset library but I have no clue whether any piece of code I wrote is correct. Unfortunately I have no access to compiler now (using Android tablet). Result of my work:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include "binary.h"

using namespace std;

void binary::add(string string1, string string2){

cin >> string1;
cin >> string2;

bitset<20> num1 (string1);
bitset<20> num2 (string2);

// not sure how to use loop operators with bitset as it's my very first piece of code and do I need to assign "c" argument first?

for(int i = 0; i < 20 ; i++){  
sum[i] = ((num1[i] ^ num2[i]) ^ c); // c is carry
c = ((num1[i] & num2[i]) | (num1[i] & c)) | (num2[i] & c); 
}

for (int j=0; i < 20; j++)
cout << sum[j];

}
```

Comment: temp2 is not 0-terminated. strcat will mess up, possibly even segfaulting on its way to the first 0 char.

Comment: Is this for educational purpose? Otherwise I'd recommend using [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) and `std::string`.

Comment: 1) How to terminate temp2 string so that strcat doesn't mess up?
2) Do you mean shifting every character right and adding "0" in the beginning? No clue on how to use std::bitset function so some example would be nice as I'm just starting to know some basics in C++ 
3)Different sizes of binary numbers won't be problematic while using bitset library?

Comment: @user4165421: Yes, `std::bitset` is for fixed lengths of bits.  If they're dynamic, either use `std::vector<bool>` or `boost::dynamic_bitset`

Comment: You want some [bignum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) library like [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/)

Comment: temp2[i+1] = 0; will solve your problem. that's how you 0-terminate a C string.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

main ()
{
    ostringstream os;
    istringstream is;

    float num=0;
    int a=8;
    b=6;

    cin >>a>>b;

    os << a << "."<< b;

    is(os.str());
    is >> num;

    cout << num;
    cout << num * 2;

    return 0;
}
```